# How to capture a Outlook Appointment delete event on custom folder?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook AddIn. One part of it that I organize appointments in a specific folder. I want to capture if an element gets deleted (in this case moving out of "my" folder counts as deleted).

I found the article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579240/how-to-capture-a-c-sharp-outlook-addin-appointment-delete-event and his/her solution helped a lot, but I have a huge problem: the event only fires in that "session", where my folder was created, not when I get the folder object from outlook.

My code looks like this:

```
private Outlook.MAPIFolder _CalendarMAPIFolder = null;
private Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_Event _CalendarFolder = null;
private Outlook.Items _CalendarItems = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder =
        this.Application.GetNamespace("mapi").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

    // get my-Folder (if not found, create it)
    try
    {
        _CalendarMAPIFolder = calendarFolder.Folders["my-Folder"];
    }
    catch
    {
        _CalendarMAPIFolder = calendarFolder.Folders.Add("my-Folder");
    }
    _CalendarItems = _CalendarMAPIFolder.Items;
    _CalendarFolder = _CalendarMAPIFolder as Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_Event;
    if (_CalendarFolder == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("can not cast MAPIFolder to Folder");
    }


    _CalendarFolder.BeforeItemMove += new Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(Folder_BeforeItemMove);
    Debug.Print("events registered");
}
public void Folder_BeforeItemMove(
        Object Item,
        Outlook.MAPIFolder MoveTo,
        ref bool Cancel)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem aitem = Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    string s = "";
    if (aitem != null) s = aitem.Subject;
    //Cancel = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Test! " + s);
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you ;)

Edit: I still have no clue :(((((((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all Microsofts fault! It was a Bug, I just needed to Update Outlook!

Answer (score 0):

By definition, [`BeforeItemMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147840%28v=office.12%29.aspx) only fires when the user (*Outlook client*) initiates an `Item` be moved. It will not fire for synchronization events (*i.e. Exchange sync*).

If you are connecting Outlook to an Exchange Server, you should look at EWS (*Exchange Web Services*) if you wish to be [notified of folder change events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579128%28v=exchg.140%29) outside the client application (*i.e. session*). EWS offers push, pull, or streaming notification options. You would attach a notification to ["Item deletion" operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. With "session" i ment the time betwean Opening Outlook and closing Outlook. -> the event only fires if i delete the folder, close outlook, open it again. ... but to delete the folder every time would destroy the sence of my addin